# Software to wake up the PC at a specific time in future (just like alarm do for mobiles when they are switched off)

Tags: windows, scheduling

To me the best internet speed is available at 2-6am, and for that purpose I want to wake up my PC automatically at 2. Can you suggest any such software to accomplish this.

Comment: Why the downvotes? It seems like a perfectly cromulent question to me (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Use Windows Task Scheduler - create a task, schedule it for 2am, and tick the power option, `Wake the computer to run this task`.

If there isn't a particular program you wish to run, just enter `cmd /c "exit"`

To make it go to sleep again at 6am, best I can think of is to make sure all applications are closed by 5:45am so the computer is idle and setup your power options in Control Panel to send your computer to sleep mode after idle for 15 minutes etc.